# Why jQuery does not work in PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am a student. I am trying to make a Jquery form validation in PHP file. But I do not know why it does not working. I made a other file but I did  not have problems.

The main is to make the validation of the strName textfield, with a Jquery function that show the div with id userName, if the text-field is null.

I checked everything but, I did not get the mistake.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function cancel() {
    location.href = "internalusers.php";
  }

  function validation() {
    valid = true;
    $('#userName').hide('fast');
    // Validation for Name of user.
    if (document.newuserform.strName.value == "") {
      $('#userName').show('fast');
      document.newuserform.strName.style = 'boder:1px solid red;';
      valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
  }
});
```

```css
.userformfields {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #006A9D;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.userformbutton {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #069;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #36C;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
}
.error {
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: #FF9797;
  color: #B00;
  border: 1px solid #990000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.erraseuserbutton {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="iconscontainer">
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="newuserform" id="newuserform" onSubmit="return validation();">
      <table align="center">
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td nowrap align="right">Nombre:</td>
          <td>
            <input class="userformfields" type="text" name="strName" value="" size="32">
            <div id="userName" class="error">Debe ingresar un nombre.</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <input class="userformbutton" type="submit" value="Crear nuevo usuario">
            <input name="cancelbutton" class="userformbutton" type="button" value="Cancelar" onClick="cancel();">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="newuserform">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Help please!

Comment: You need to state in the question ([edit]) in what way it does not work (error message, or undesired behavior, not just "it does not work") and what you expected it to do.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrapped the code in a document.ready method so the validation method is not global. So you can not call the function. DO NOT wrap all your code in document.ready

Comment: Thanks! I unwrap the code of the documente.ready. The function cancel works perfect, but the Jquery code does not. :-(

Answer (score 0):

In your **`<Form>`** tag you might want to use onSubmit="validation();" instead of onSubmit="return validation();"